# Excel2LaTeX code not working in LaTeX

Tags: tables, booktabs, excel2latex

```
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{ccccccc}
    \toprule
    \multirow{2}[4]{*}{\textbf{Gauge Number}} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{Load (N)}} \\
    \midrule
          & \textbf{0} & \textbf{100} & \textbf{200} & \textbf{300} & \textbf{400} & \textbf{500} \\
    1     & -128  & -230  & -332  & -434  & -538  & -649 \\
    2     & 35    & -37   & -108  & -179  & -252  & -329 \\
    3     & 1089  & 1089  & 1089  & 1089  & 1049  & 973 \\
    4     & 5     & -9    & -22   & -36   & -48   & -63 \\
    5     & 1088  & 1088  & 1088  & 1088  & 1088  & 1088 \\
    6     & 77    & 96    & 116   & 134   & 156   & 175 \\
    7     & 731   & 751   & 771   & 792   & 814   & 836 \\
    8     & 129   & 172   & 217   & 261   & 309   & 355 \\
    9     & 58    & 104   & 149   & 195   & 243   & 293 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
```

Excel2LaTeX produced the following code but I keep getting errors saying 'undefined control sequence \toprule' among other undefined control sequences. I'm new to LaTeX so are there certain packages I need to load before using this code?

Comment: Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 4):

For me it works (but it is looking bad, because of the code)

You probably forgot `\usepackage{booktabs}` (but I can't be sure because of the missing MWE).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{ccccccc}
    \toprule
    \multirow{2}[4]{*}{\textbf{Gauge Number}} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{Load (N)}} \\
    \midrule
          & \textbf{0} & \textbf{100} & \textbf{200} & \textbf{300} & \textbf{400} & \textbf{500} \\
    1     & -128  & -230  & -332  & -434  & -538  & -649 \\
    2     & 35    & -37   & -108  & -179  & -252  & -329 \\
    3     & 1089  & 1089  & 1089  & 1089  & 1049  & 973 \\
    4     & 5     & -9    & -22   & -36   & -48   & -63 \\
    5     & 1088  & 1088  & 1088  & 1088  & 1088  & 1088 \\
    6     & 77    & 96    & 116   & 134   & 156   & 175 \\
    7     & 731   & 751   & 771   & 792   & 814   & 836 \\
    8     & 129   & 172   & 217   & 261   & 309   & 355 \\
    9     & 58    & 104   & 149   & 195   & 243   & 293 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: result]

To enhance the code change you could replace `\multirow{2}[4]{*}{\textbf{Gauge Number}}` by `\textbf{Gauge Number}` and move `\midrule` one row down.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{ccccccc}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Gauge Number} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{Load (N)}} \\
          & \textbf{0} & \textbf{100} & \textbf{200} & \textbf{300} & \textbf{400} & \textbf{500} \\
    \midrule
    1     & -128  & -230  & -332  & -434  & -538  & -649 \\
    2     & 35    & -37   & -108  & -179  & -252  & -329 \\
    3     & 1089  & 1089  & 1089  & 1089  & 1049  & 973 \\
    4     & 5     & -9    & -22   & -36   & -48   & -63 \\
    5     & 1088  & 1088  & 1088  & 1088  & 1088  & 1088 \\
    6     & 77    & 96    & 116   & 134   & 156   & 175 \\
    7     & 731   & 751   & 771   & 792   & 814   & 836 \\
    8     & 129   & 172   & 217   & 261   & 309   & 355 \\
    9     & 58    & 104   & 149   & 195   & 243   & 293 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}
```

\end{document}

result:

[image]

Comment: An MWE? Could I attach the excel file so that I can show what I want the table to look like?

Comment: @DavidO'Sullivan See [here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) about a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). The code you provided won't result in the error you mentioned (missing `\documentclass` etc.). MWE doesn't mean the code should work without the problem you have.

Comment: @DavidO'Sullivan If you are happy with this solution, you may accept it (use the check mark).